# 'call procedure_name ()' statement is seen on the processlist

Tags: mysql

When I see MySQL processlist, I don't see actual executing queries for one of the procedures; and always that procedure is shown like 'call abc()', running for a significantly high time like 4000 sec, on the processlist.

I'm not able to understand why it just shows the call statement and not the actual queries running in it?

Note: This is one of the sub-procedure called from another procedure in the system.

Attaching herewith the processlist view:

**# Id   User        Host        db      Command      Time       State       Info**

123  myuser      1.2.3.4:123     abc     Query       **3900**   **Sending data**    **call abc()**

Comment: What does `SELECT VERSION();` return? I am testing calling a procedure on MySQL 5.7, and I see the query, not the `CALL` statement. That matches the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-processlist.html): *"The statement might be the one sent to the server, or an innermost statement if the statement executes other statements. For example, if a CALL statement executes a stored procedure that is executing a SELECT statement, the Info value shows the SELECT statement."*

Comment: If the processlist shows 'call abc()' for a long time than server prepares this procedure execution during this time.

Comment: @Akina Preparing the procedure *for 4000 seconds?* What's this running on, a 286?

Comment: @BillKarwin The server is an entity without imagination. If it writes 'call sub', it means that it has already passed this line, but did not get to the nearest SELECT or other, which is displayed as an action in the processlist.

Comment: Then I think the OP should show their procedure code, so we can see what lines it could be stuck on before it gets to the first query. I just tested, and I see that even `SET @foo = <expr>;` shows up in my processlist. It doesn't have to be a more traditional DML query.